# How to disable bash drivers in windows 8.1?

Tags: bash, windows-8.1, drivers, device-manager, symantec

I'm trying to follow these [instructions](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO59193.html) to stop Bash Driver BHDrvx86 or BHDdrvx64, but device manager in Windows 8.1 no longer displays non plug and play drivers (such as the Bash drivers), even as a hidden option. I'm unsure how else to disable them.

Comment: It says "b. Choose View > Show hidden devices and look for the driver under 'Non-Plug and Play Drivers'". There is no 'Non-Plug and Play Drivers'

Comment: You can use Autoruns to delete and/or disable these drivers.  You sure these drivers are even installed based on your last comment.

Comment: you have a point. I'll see how it goes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't disable what was never there.

Answer (score 2):

Device Manager generally should be run elevated, it doesn't show many things otherwise.

However, the same can be done from an elevated command line:

```
sc config BHDrvx86 start= disabled
sc config BHDdrvx64 start= disabled
```

*(A space only after the `=` sign, exactly as shown in the example.)*

Comment: putting a space before and after the = in command prompt, i got Description, Usage, Options (and under it Note), each with it's own instructions. Is that correct?

Comment: @ErljaJkdf.: No, it isn't. You need to specify `start=` as a single word, like in the example. It's why I added that comment in the first place...

Comment: Alright, clarified.

Comment: The correct version is giving me [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.